# Given a point $c$ in a field $Z_p$. Can we get another value $c^{'}$ such that $\left(c^{\prime}-c\right)$ is invertible in $Z_p$?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, random-number-generator, finite-field

If we have a point in a field $c$. Can we get another value $c^{'}$  such that 
$\left(c^{\prime}-c\right)$ is invertible in $Z_p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{Z}_p$ all points $c\neq 0,$ are invertible.

Choosing any $c'\neq c$ will give you $c-c' \neq 0,$ thus it will be invertible.

Comment: Are you sure? How you define invertible?

Comment: It's a field, for all nonzero $u$ there is $u^{-1}$ such that $u^{-1}u=1\pmod p.$

Comment: Every element in the field is coprime with $p$ since it's prime. That means that every element is an unit and it has a multiplicative inverse in the group $Z{_p}^*$. If the modulus wasn't coprime then $c'-c$ could be a non unit depending on the result of the substraction.

Comment: is this means that the result of (c'-c) should be invertible?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means since $c-c'$ is nonzero if and only if $c\neq c'$ in $Z_p$.